# Send email from alternate address

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

So we had a perfectly good, working email solution in our GAE app. We could send email from noreply@company.com as desired. noreply@company.com was a GAE account with dev access in our app.

Next, we wanted to use the SMTP server associated with this account. To do this, we needed to upgrade the account to use gmail. As we proceeded with this, Google informed us that we would need to associate a gmail address with this account - we chose company.noreply@gmail.com. noreply@company.com would become an alternate address. We then made noreply@company.com the default address. Now we could use the smtp server remotely, sending email from noreply@company.com. Great.

The next day, we found out this broke the mailer on our GAE app. In Permissions, the account had changed from noreply@company.com to company.noreply@gmail.com. Re-inviting noreply@company.com proceeded successfully, but in the end the account stayed as company.noreply@gmail.com. noreply@company.com is now unauthorized to send mail, or put another way, we are unable to set noreply@company.com as the from address, even though that is an authorized account.

Is there any way to restore the ability to send email from no reply@company.com through GAE?

--

Current code:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

try {
    final Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("noreply@company.com"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(content, contentType);

    Transport.send(msg);
} catch (final MessagingException ex) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

We've invited noreply@company.com to be an admin, and it has been accepted successfully, and listed in GAE Permissions, albeit under the alternate address.

Here's the error GAE gives, when trying to send email using that approved account:

```
Internal Server Error (500) - The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:517)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.post(ServerResource.java:1216)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unauthorized Sender: Unauthorized sender
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.doSend(MailServiceImpl.java:109)
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.send(MailServiceImpl.java:34)
    at com.glasseystrategy.jstratpad.util.MailUtils.sendEmailReport(MailUtils.java:400)
...
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring GAE/Gmail, and not about programming or software development.

Comment: No, it's all about programming and software development. Often, when you are developing complex apps, you need to send email from the program. In this case we need to send email from a GAE app, using a particular from address. To do that, you must do some configuring. Here's a reference for you: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail

So the question remains - how to get GAE to send email from this address, given the state we are currently in? Any code is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved as an acknowledged bug in GAE. It's currently not possible, nor is there a workaround to my knowledge (other than using a different email address).

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1107